# Gab es früher gravierende Veränderungen des Vokabulars der deutschen Sprache?

Tags: vocabulary, history

Wie Sie bereits festgestellt haben, hat sich der deutsche Wortschatz wegen der Digitalisierung um mehrere hundert Wörter bereichert, z. B. *liken, surfen, posten,* usw. Gab es jedoch auch in der Vergangenheit solche Veränderungen der Sprache, die von verschiedenen Ereignissen, etwa den Weltkriegen, der Erfindung des Telefons oder des elektrischen Lichts, hervorgerufen wurden? Was sind Beispiele hierfür?

Comment: Das ist, mit Verlaub, keine besonders sinnvolle Frage, die sich außerdem ein bißchen nach "mach' mir meine Hausaufgabe" anhört. **Natürlich** musste sich in der Vergangenheit die Sprache ständig anpassen, um Begriffe für Dinge, die vorher nicht da waren, zu finden.

Comment: @tofro Eigentlich suche ich nach Belegen, dass die Sprache mit der Entwicklung der Gesellschaft zusammenhängt

Comment: @tofro: Insbesondere das "Wie Sie bereits festgestellt haben" am Anfang deutet darauf hin, dass der Text aus einem anderen Kontext stammt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Das Deutsche wurde schon immer von anderen Sprachen beeinflusst.

Im Mittelalter war der Einfluss des Lateinischen sehr groß. Viele Wörter, die wir heute als urdeutsch wahrnehmen, stammen aus dem Lateinischen (z.B. Kampf, Fenster, Keller)

Besonders im 17. und 18. Jahrhundert sind dann viele Wörter aus dem Französischen übernommen worden. Im 19. und Anfang des 20. Jahrhunderts versuchte man diese Wörter wieder zu verbannen und durch Wörter deutschen Ursprungs zu ersetzen (z.B. Trottoir/Bürgersteig, Portemonnaie/Geldbeutel). Der Kampf um die "Reinheit" der Sprache ist also nichts Neues.

Comment: +1 Und es gab auch schon früher Versuche, vermeintlich Fremdes zu „verdeutschen“, etwa im 17. Jhd. bei Philipp von Zesen. Manche seiner Schöpfungen haben sich gehalten (Augenblick, Bücherei), andere nicht (Meuchelpuffer).

Comment: Das Mittelalter scheint mir ein bißchen spät für den lateinischen Spracheinfluß. Die Römer dürften sehr viel mehr Wörter hinterlassen haben, als sie noch da waren ;) - Nur nicht in der deutschen Sprache, sondern in ihren Vorgängern... Dein Zeitrahmen für den französischen Spracheinfluß scheint mir auch um 100 Jahre daneben - Der grösste Einfluß der französchischen Sprache dürfte in der "Franzosenzeit" also 1792-1815 gewesen sein.

Comment: Das mag für stark eingedeutsche Lehnwörter gelten. Aber man darf nicht vergessen, dass Latein im Mittelalter die Sprache der Intellektuellen und der Universitäten war. Wer in Deutschland publizieren, aber außerhalb Deutschlands gelesen werden wollte, musste das auf Latein tun, so wie heutzutage international nur das zählt, was auf Englisch veröffentlicht wurde.

Comment: Das ist aber keine besondere Eigenschaft der deutschen Sprache. **Jede** lebende Sprache macht immerfort solche Veränderungen durch, und sogar Sprachen, die offiziell als tot gelten, wie z.B. Latein, verändern sich (wenn auch erheblich langsamer).